# Div and Button element collision when floating

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<div class="site-branding">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/Test/"        rel="home">Test</a></h1>
</div>

<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">Navigation</button>
```

On my CSS, I put site-branding to float left and then menu-toggle to float right. On normal resolutions, the display is good. The brand is at the left side of the header and the menu-toggle is at the right but when the screen gets smaller, I want the menu toggle button to be below the site-branding div but the behavior that I got is that the menu-toggle is colliding with the site-branding div. Any ideas how to resolve this? thank you.

Comment: Pop your CSS in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Float will ignore the element's collision box. You will have to use media queries to apply new CSS to your header when the screen is too small.

For example, if your branding is 300px wide and your toggle is 60px wide, you should use a media query of `max-width: 360px`, target another CSS file that will place the toggle below your branding image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what does happens if you float these elements:

```css
.headline {
  float: right;
}
.btn {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="headline">Some link to your homepage</h1>
</div>
<button class="btn">some button</button>
```

(press fullscreen and resize your browser window)
The button element floats below the headline.

Now can you add the css classes for the button and site-title?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the answer as you like if it rewrite it as follows. You just adjust the width of the div as you like.

**Css**

.FloatClass{float:left;}

**Html**

```
<div class="FloatClass">
      <h1 class="headline">Some link to your homepage</h1>
    </div>
<div class="FloatClass">
    <button class="btn">some button</button>
</div>
```

All the best